# Why does this Ajax request work in Greasemonkey but not Tampermonkey?

Tags: jquery, ajax, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I cannot find any compatability problems listed anywhere that would explain why this works in Greasemonkey, but not Tampermonkey. It doesn't appear to be pulling the text file at all.

```
function getClosings() {
    var url = "https://googledrive.com/host/0B1RCGCyAlYoJfnU3WGFERUtUUEF2V1NDY00yNWtSNWFfUkstSHJsZGNab1U5VHFnRFU5ems/vdxclosings.txt", result = "";

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(txt) {
            result = txt;
        },
        async:false
    });

    var array = parseClosingsToArray(result);
    return array;
}

function parseClosingsToArray(txt)
{
    var closings = [];
    var lines = txt.split('\n');
    for (var i=0; i<lines.length; i++)
    {
        var line = lines[i];
        line = line.replace('[', '').replace(']', ''); // remove brackets
        line = line.replace(/["']/g, "");
        line = line.replace('\n', "");

        if (line.indexOf(',') != -1)
        {
            var parts = line.split(',');        
            var code = parts[0];
            var info = parts[1];
            var row = [code, info];
            closings.push(row);
        }

    }

    return closings;
}
```

Comment: `async:false` is a terrible practice ... don't use it

Comment: checked your JS console for errors/warnings?

Comment: The only error I get is that unsafe window is not defined, but I don't see how that would apply to this script.

Comment: So this is not working because I believe of the Origin policy. The URL changes when accessed. It starts off as what I have in the script, but when you access the url, it changes to something unique.

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch to gm_xmlhttprequest and change a few things.

```
function handleClosings() {
    GM_xmlhttpRequest({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://googledrive.com/host/0B1RCGCyAlYoJfnU3WGFERUtUUEF2V1NDY00yNWtSNWFfUkstSHJsZGNab1U5VHFnRFU5ems/vdxclosings.txt",
        synchronous: true,
        onload: function(response) {
            result = response.responseText;
            var array = parseClosingsToArray(result);            
            modifyHtmlWithClosings(array);            
        }
    });
}
```